# Polar Decomposition vs. Orthogonal Decomposition of Linear Operators on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $\mathsf{Lin}$ denote the vector space of linear operators under addition and scalar multiplication on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then we have the orthogonal decomposition $\mathsf{Lin} = \mathsf{Skw} \oplus \mathsf{Sym}$, where $\mathsf{Skw}$ is the space of skew operators and $\mathsf{Sym}$ denotes the space of symmetric operators and where $\oplus$ denotes the direct product.

But for some ${\bf F} \in \mathsf{Lin}$, we also have the polar decomposition ${\bf F} ={\bf R} {\bf U}$, where ${\bf R} \in \mathsf{Orth}$ and ${\bf U} \in \mathsf{Sym}$, where $\mathsf{Orth}$ is the group of orthogonal linear operators. However, I guess from this perspective $\mathsf{Lin}$, $\mathsf{Orth}$, and $\mathsf{Sym}$ are to be interpreted as groups under composition. Is there a name for a group-like direct product, so that I may decompose the group $\mathsf{Lin} = \mathsf{Sym} \text{(symbol)} \mathsf{Orth}$? This space has no inner product defined and hence no notion of orthogonal subgroups exists. Thanks.

Comment: Lin is not a group because you cannot invert any linear operator. Sym neither is a group

Comment: you are considering in fact the algebra of linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^3$ : a vector space (addition, multiplication with scalar), and multiplication between elements : the composition of linear operators (matrix multiplication). it's called an algebra because on those, you can define polynomials $P(M) = \sum_{k=0}^K c_k M^k$